# What is the best and most practical way to mimic the "Menu button" behavior / OR / card stack custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

I need to create a new view that will contain a stack of cards, similar to what the Menu softkey does. After googling and trying things out, I saw that the menu button relies on a `com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView` class, however - i really just need a stack of cards that respond to touches, so i can implement my logic in their onTouch or a custom onTouchListener.

What I really need is this - a displayable stack of cards, so that they're on top of each other, fully displaying only one card and displaying the header of the previous few cards, and potentially the header of the next card.

I have the CardView all setup. I'm kinda having problems properly implementing my CardStackView due to the fact that `CardStackView extends ScrollView` hit a brickwall due to the fact that ScrollView simply steals all touch events even when i use `scroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`. I've also tried `CardStackview extends FrameLayout` and tried keeping everything in check myself, however i somewhat ran into layouting issues there (all cards were simply "one card" meaning they all positioned themselves on top of the layout, AS WELL as not responding to touch events).

Now, i'm really looking for a solution or hints to how I could mimic the menu button (it actually shows current/recent activities as scrollable cards) as a custom View. I'm down to my almost-last attempt at basing my wrapper view as `CardStackView extends ViewGroup` and trying that.

Guys (and gals) - please help, i'm running out of options here while i'm not really *really* working on implementing the view, rather than trying out different bases i could use so i'd have a bit less work to do. I'm down to ViewGroup :/ I would really like it if I don't have to go as low as `CardStackView extends View` and re-inventing the wheel and doing everything myself.

So, borrowing or copypasting or replicating the "Menu button press" behaviour/look&feel would really help me out, since it really looks like what I'm looking for and my objective. Once i get cards stacked like that, i can fully devote myself to implementing the proper logic and tweaks either in the onTouch() or wherever needed really.

I hope I explained the problem clearly, however if I did not - feel free to ask more via comments and I will respond while trying my luck with the current ViewGroup idea. CardView extends LinearLayout, while for CardStackView (which is a compound control from what i've read online) I've tried extending ScrollView, FrameLayout and am trying with ViewGroup :/

Please men (and women), help a fellow dev out :)

EDIT1:
After receiving the "you need to be more concise" comment, i figured to better explain the situation.

I'm trying to create a custom view that looks and behaves closely like the one you see when you press the menu buttons (when the activities are all stacked in a stack of cards). The cards need to be clickable, and draggable - meaning they need to respond to touch events. The best explanation I had was to compare it with the "menu button" example.

concise problem - what to base the "stack of cards" view on? ViewGroup? Something better? I have no real problem posting the full code here like i did for my "edittext-on-demand" view, but for now i'm just looking for some hints, tips and pointers on how to best tackle the problem. I've wasted two days on it already.

EDIT2: The CardStackView will need to dynamically inflate and add other CardViews (custom view)

Comment: why the downvotes without comments on what needs improvement? please...

Comment: I find this really interesting and upvoted. However I guess you could be more kind of concise.

Comment: @miav sure, i can explain more. just tell what needs to be better explained :) 
the "tl;dr" version is - i need a view that looks just like the one you see when you press the menu button and see all your recent activities stacked like a stack of cards.

Comment: I think that could be interesting to follow. Hope someone can help you.